# Is there a way to make the Scala REPL not stop with CTRL-C

Tags: scala, user-interface, read-eval-print-loop

I'm using the Scala REPL to interactively test some hash functions I'm building. I'm  constantly switching between the product code (Eclipse), the browser and the Scala interpreter, doing copy/paste of values and results. In the mix I'm often doing CTRL-C on the interpreter, exiting the session and loosing all my functions.

Is there any way to let the Scala REPL either ignore CTRL-C or, even better, perform "paste" with it?  I'm working on Linux.

Comment: On Windows we have the opposite problem: if you want to kill a scala command (infinite loop etc) you have to close the whole window because CTRL-C does nothing! It might help to know that in your home directory there should be a file called `.scala_history` that contains your REPL commands.

Comment: Which version of Scala? On my machine, Ctrl-C in the REPL will stop a running command, but not exit the REPL. I'm using Scala 2.9.1 and OS X.

Comment: On windows you can hit CTRL-D to exit the REPL.

Comment: @Kipton Barros I'm using version 2.9.0.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I only know how to prevent REPL from exiting. Remapping of `CTRL+C` to perform copy command could be done in the same way (*if there is some command that ables to change keymap w/out restarting terminal -- I don't know is there one*). Anyways, to block `^C` wrap your REPL invocation in .sh script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#switch off sensitivity to ^C
trap '' 2

# here goes REPL invoke
scala

#get back sensitivity to ^C
trap 2
```

trap command

> defines and activates handlers to be run when the shell receives
>   signals
>       or other conditions.

2 is a [SIGINT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_%28POSIX%29) value (that's the signal which is triggered when you press `CTRL+C`)

Comment: Thanks. This sent me in a good direction. Finally I used `stty intr \^k` to redirect `Ctrl-C` to `Ctrl-K` (in case I still would need BREAK to interrupt any dumbness I might create.)  The scala startup script has a step to save the terminal settings and it will restore it on exit. So I put said command after `# save terminal settings`. Works like a charm.

Comment: or you could just create an alias instead of a script @om-nom-nom mentioned.  
 `alias scala="trap '' 2 ; scala"`

Comment: ^: Something like `alias scala="bash -c \"trap '' SIGINT; scala\""` would be more useful, so it only affects scala process, not the current/interactive bash session. Also, it's good to be an alias since it's only going to be used interactively (not called from another program).

Answer (score 1):

The repl already intercepts ctrl-C, but apparently it doesn't work on linux.  It does work on osx.  If someone who uses linux opens a ticket with sufficient detail to indicate why not, I can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the native Scala REPL, you can use [**Ammonite**](http://www.lihaoyi.com/Ammonite/#Ammonite), which [does handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>](http://www.lihaoyi.com/Ammonite/#Interruptingrun-awayexecutionwithCtrl-C):

```
@ while(true) ()
... hangs ...
^Ctrl-C
Interrupted!

@
```

> The traditional Scala REPL doesn't handle runaway code, and gives you no option but to kill the process, losing all your work.
>   **Ammonite-REPL lets you interrupt the thread, stop the runaway-command and keep going**.